# Java, is it possible to create a program (TCP) that listens to both serversockets and normal socket ports?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

In my Java program I created two sockets, one of them serversocket and one of them is just the normal socket. 

I setup the serverSocket at port 1234 and made another normal port to listen at localhost:1234.

The socket doesn't recieve any of the messages I'm sending to it though.

p.s. It also receives messages on my other Java program listening on the same port. But not from the same program, with both the serversocket and the normal socket.

EDIT: here's my code.

```
public void initLan(){
    try{
        if(mode == GameMode.TWO_PLAYER_LAN_HOST){
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            System.out.println("Waiting for client to connect....");
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
            serverInputSocket = new Socket("localhost",port);
            lanHostInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(serverInputSocket.getInputStream()));
            lanHostOutput = new PrintWriter(serverInputSocket.getOutputStream(),true);
        }else if(mode == GameMode.TWO_PLAYER_LAN_CLIENT){
            socket = new Socket("localhost",port);
        }
        lanOutput = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
        lanInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Could not initialize LAN");
    }
}
```

and here's the message I send when I press the up key

```
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
            lanOutput.print("UP\n");
            lanOutput.flush();
            lanHostOutput.print("UP\n");
            lanHostOutput.flush();
            //System.out.println("UP");
        }
```

When I send the message, it is never received later on in the program.

```
if(lanInput.ready()){
            String message = lanInput.readLine();
            System.out.println(message);
            if(message.contains("UP")){
                snake.move("UP");
                System.out.println("moved up");
            }
        }
        if(mode == GameMode.TWO_PLAYER_LAN_HOST){
            if(lanHostInput.ready()){
                String message = lanInput.readLine();
                System.out.println(message);
                if(message.contains("UP")){
                    snake.move("UP");
                    System.out.println("moved up");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: what do you means with "another normal port to listen at ..."? Only server sockets listen for connections; other sockets do not listen, they connect to a port where a server socket is listening on the other side. Show your code for both the server and client side, so that we can tell if there's anything wrong with it.

Comment: added code and changed it from listen to connect.

Comment: also, the client and server side are both on the same program. That's probably why there's an issue. Worked perfectly when I had it in two seperate programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two classes in java for socket 
1) java.net.Socket: for client sockets
2) java.net.ServerSocket: for server sockets

you can only listen on server sockets not client sockets

the problem is these two lines

```
socket = serverSocket.accept();
serverInputSocket = new Socket("localhost",port);
```

replace them with this one

```
serverInputSocket = serverSocket.accept();
```